# Как реализовать многопроцессорность в чат боте для telegram

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, aiogram, multiprocessing

Я пишу чат бота telegram для парсинга сайтов который по запросу пользователя будет парсить и выдавать подходящую информацию с выбранного сайта и использую для этого асинхронную библиотеку `aiogram`. Все работает исправно, но я хочу увеличить скорость парсинга путем реализации многопроцессорности в моем коде, так же я планирую увеличивать количество ядер для многопроцессорности используемых сервером на котором будет стоять мой бот при увеличении количества пользователей использующих парсер одновременно.

При реализации многопроцессорности столкнулся с проблемой, при использовании `Pool` скрипт выдает ошибку при взаимодействии с асинхронной функцией. Ниже приведен код в котором я воспроизвел эту проблему

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests
import time

bot=Bot(token)
dp=Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
kortej=[[('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=1', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=2', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=3', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=4', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=5', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=6', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=7', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=8', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=9', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=10', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=11', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=12', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=13', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=14', 1762474)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=15', 1762474901), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=16', 1762474)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=17', 1762474901), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=18', 1762474)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=19', 1762474901), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=20', 1762474)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=21', 1762474901), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=22', 1762474)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=23', 1762474), ('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=24', 1762474901)], [('https://www.olx.pl/dom-ogrod/?page=25', 1762474901)]]

async def requests_get(kortej):
    url=kortej[0]
    ID=kortej[1]
    print(ID)
    requests.get(url)
    requests.get(url)
    requests.get(url)
    requests.get(url)

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def pool_handler(message: types.Message):
    for i in kortej:
        pool=Pool(2)
        pool.map(requests_get, i)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

А вот ошибка которую я получаю при запуске программы:

```
C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:138: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'requests_get' was never awaited
  task = job = result = func = args = kwds = None
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=<MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<coroutine object requests_get at 0x000001E0A04C2D50>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'coroutine' object")'>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "Q:\python\p\p\pypy.py", line 34, in pool_handler
    pool.map(requests_get, i)
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\79189\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<coroutine object requests_get at 0x000001E0A04C2D50>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'coroutine' object")'
```

Я хочу узнать возможные решения моей проблемы. Буду благодарен за любой совет

Comment: requests_get не должна быть асинхронной. она же выполняется в отдельном процессе. Асинхронно возвращается лишь ее результат, который должен быть обычным текстом, что бы его можно было передать между процессами. Если внутри нее надо обрабатывать что то асинхронное, то она должна будет сама стартовать свой цикл ожидания событий

Comment: У меня нет цели сделать `requests` запросы асинхронными. Меня интересует реализация многопроцессорности с асинхронными функциями

Comment: async перед функцией requests_get уберите и должно заработать.

Comment: Тут больше бы подошло бы многопоточность.И зачем в функций requests_get четыре раз подряд  requests.get(url)?

Comment: У вас есть цель увеличить скорость парсинга, многопроцессорность на мной взгляд не лучшее решение. При одном ядре скорость выполнения кода не будет отличатся от синхроного кода. На мной взгляд было бы уместнее использовать асинхроность или многопаточность.

Comment: @СергейШашко Я думаю у ТС в парсинге интересует не получение html результата, а последующий его разбор, который собственно процессор и требует. И вот тут большой вопрос помогут ли например потоки, я например не знаю как beautifulsoup работает с GIL. Если он ее вдруг не освобождает, то потоки не помогут. А процессы как раз то что понадобится.

Comment: @Mike. Я вас понял. Код ТС как раз говорит нам что он хочет ускорит получения html результата причем посылая запросы пачками(многопроцессорность)  Львиная доля времени займут запросы для парсера вот где будет затык. И последующия обработка не ускорится.

Comment: дело в том что парсером одновременно будут пользоваться десятки человек. Я хочу реализовать многопроцессорность с ассинхронными функциями `async` потому как внутри этих функций будет прописана отправка результатов пользователю использующему бота например: `await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text')` в общем ассинхронность в моем коде нужна для правильной одновременной работы бота с несколькими пользователями, а многопроцессорность нужна для увеличения скорости работы бота потому как чем больше человек пользуется ботом, тем медленнее он работает (извиняюсь за тавтологию)